# sp::over vs sf::st_intersection in r

Tags: r, sp, sf

I was wondering why sf::st_intersection() takes too much time, in comparison with sp::over(); I use sf for pretty much all of my geospatial workflows (I was used to sp as well), and more and more packages are building support for sf objects; is there a way for speeding up st_intersection? According to st_intersection man page: "A spatial index is built on argument x", so I can't build a spatial index to speed it up.

In the following example eke is a point (sp or sf) object and ver_poly is a polygon object, even coerced to "Spatial", sp::over() goes faster (just using 10000 points, whole object is 150000 features):

```
> system.time(en_ver <- over(eke[1:10000,], as(ver_poly, "Spatial")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.573   0.004   0.576 
> system.time(eke[1:10000,] %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("longitud", "latitud")) %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>%
+   st_intersection(ver_poly))
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
   user  system elapsed 
 83.552   0.004  83.585
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting from sf to sp in the first, and from from sp to sf in the second - you should avoid timing those conversions.

`sf` *is* sometimes slow with points because of the way they are stored, but what you gain is far greater consistency than with sp, and *usually faster ops*.

Here I think it is comparable, but will depend on your actual data.

Here's a like-to-like comparison.  You need `st_intersects` for the analog to what `over` is doing here.

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.0, GDAL 2.4.0, PROJ 5.2.0
sp_pts <- do.call(rbind, replicate(25, quakes, simplify = FALSE))

coordinates(sp_pts) <- c("long", "lat")
proj4string(sp_pts) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
sf_pts <- st_as_sf(sp_pts)
sp_poly <- raster::rasterToPolygons(raster::raster(sp_pts))
sp_poly$layer <- 1:nrow(sp_poly)
sf_poly <- st_as_sf(sp_poly)


plot(sp_poly)
plot(sp_pts, add = TRUE, pch = ".")
```

[image]

```r
 system.time({sp_ov <- over(sp_pts, sp_poly)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.191   0.004   0.195
 system.time({sf_ov <- st_intersects(sf_pts, sf_poly)})
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.21    0.00    0.21

 str(unlist(sp_ov$layer))
#>  int [1:25000] 38 37 59 28 38 39 1 68 68 27 ...
 str(unlist(unclass(sf_ov)))
#>  int [1:25000] 38 37 59 28 38 39 1 68 68 27 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>